# Using HAVING COUNT(column name) NOT working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the SQL statement, working in SQL Server 2016, below where I'm getting records from an INNER SELECT UNION ALL statement and in the OUTER SELECT I'm trying to extract those records that meet the HAVING COUNT code however, my code is bringing back no records.
Here are the records from my INNER SELECT statement with UNION ALL:

| LocationSysID | LocationName | AgentNo | RepID | RepName | Count | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | A-MAX | 22810 | 17025 | mel | 339 | 1 |
| 43 | ADV | 21371 | 17025 | mel | 100 | 1 |
| 43 | ADV | 21371 | 17025 | mel | 0 | 2 |
| 94 | ALPINE | 21249 | 17025 | mel | 64 | 1 |
| 94 | ALPINE | 21249 | 17025 | mel | 0 | 2 |
| 126 | AMS | 21537 | 17025 | mel | 333 | 1 |
| 138 | ADV | 22812 | 17025 | mel | 1180 | 1 |

I am trying via the OUTER SELECT to get those records from the INNER select statement where the COUNT(LocationSysID) > 1.  So that the 4 records where the LocationSysID is 43 and 94 would be returned.

Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT x.LocationSysID, x.LocationName, x.AgentNo, x.RepID, x.RepName, x.TotalCount, x.RN
FROM (
    SELECT q.LocationSysID, q.LocationName, q.AgentNo, q.RepID, q.RepName, q.QuoteCount as TotalCount, '1' as RN
    FROM #tempYesQuotes q 
    WHERE q.QuoteCount > 0
    --ORDER BY LocationSysID asc;

    UNION ALL

    SELECT p.LocationSysID, p.LocationName, p.AgentNo, p.RepID, p.RepName, p.PolicyCount as TotalCount, '2' as RN
    FROM #tempNoNewPolicies p
    WHERE p.PolicyCount = 0
    --ORDER BY LocationSysID asc, RN asc;
) x
GROUP BY LocationSysID, LocationName, AgentNo, RepID, RepName, TotalCount, RN
HAVING COUNT(LocationSysID) > 1  
ORDER BY LocationSysID asc, RN asc;
```

Comment: Your desired outcome is not clear. Why you wrote that you want to see in the result 4 records where the LocationSysID is 43 and 94? Two of those records have count = 0. Why you don't want to see records with other `LocationSysID`, such as 5, 126, 138? Their count is more than 1.

Comment: I only want those records where the LocationSysID is in the result set more than 1 time.  That is why I only want to see LocationSysID 43 and 94.  Sorry I should have clarified.  I don't care about those records where the LocationSysID only has one record.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: OK, the column called `Count` confused me. I understand now that you don't care about values in this columns. You are interested in the number of rows.

Comment: Correct.  I understood that the HAVING COUNT clause would give me those records that have a COUNT of a specified column listed more than once.  Apparently I have a wrong understanding and therefore the reason for my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the results that you describe in the question is because you group by all these fields:

```
GROUP BY LocationSysID, LocationName, AgentNo, RepID, RepName, TotalCount, RN
```

The values in `TotalCount` and `RN` are not the same, so each group has one row. Hence `COUNT()` function never returns anything but `1`.

So, if you simply change your `GROUP BY` clause and remove columns `TotalCount, RN` from it you'll get the results that you expect.
But, with the query structure that you have you'll have to remove these columns from the final result set as well.

I'm guessing that you want to keep them. To achieve that I'd recommend to use windowed `COUNT() OVER()` function instead of a plain `COUNT`.

I am using CTEs here to make the query readable. You can inline them into one large query if you want. It doesn't affect the performance.

```
WITH
CTE_Union
AS
(
    SELECT q.LocationSysID, q.LocationName, q.AgentNo, q.RepID, q.RepName, q.QuoteCount as TotalCount, '1' as RN
    FROM #tempYesQuotes q 
    WHERE q.QuoteCount > 0
    --ORDER BY LocationSysID asc;

    UNION ALL

    SELECT p.LocationSysID, p.LocationName, p.AgentNo, p.RepID, p.RepName, p.PolicyCount as TotalCount, '2' as RN
    FROM #tempNoNewPolicies p
    WHERE p.PolicyCount = 0
    --ORDER BY LocationSysID asc, RN asc;
)
,CTE_RowCount
AS
(
    SELECT
        LocationSysID, LocationName, AgentNo, RepID, RepName, TotalCount, RN
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY LocationSysID) AS LocationCount
    FROM
        CTE_Union
)
SELECT
    LocationSysID, LocationName, AgentNo, RepID, RepName, TotalCount, RN
FROM
    CTE_RowCount
WHERE
    LocationCount > 1
ORDER BY
    LocationSysID asc, RN asc
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Outer select, `CTE` helps you to get some clear picture

Try the below

```
;WITH X
AS
    (
    SELECT q.LocationSysID, q.LocationName, q.AgentNo, q.RepID, q.RepName, q.QuoteCount as TotalCount, '1' as RN
    FROM #tempYesQuotes q 
    WHERE q.QuoteCount > 0
    --ORDER BY LocationSysID asc;

    UNION ALL

    SELECT p.LocationSysID, p.LocationName, p.AgentNo, p.RepID, p.RepName, p.PolicyCount as TotalCount, '2' as RN
    FROM #tempNoNewPolicies p
    WHERE p.PolicyCount = 0
    --ORDER BY LocationSysID asc, RN asc;
    )
SELECT x.LocationSysID, x.LocationName, x.AgentNo, x.RepID, x.RepName, x.TotalCount, x.RN
WHERE X.LocationSysID IN(SELECT X1.LocationSysID FROM X X1 GROUP BY X1.LocationSysID HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
ORDER BY X.LocationSysID asc, X.RN asc;
```